# Mysql slow-query only in script, but not in phpmyadmin. How to solve that?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a simple select statement without any join.
All it does is checking a date_time and some other flags

table has about 45.000 entries.
The query is performed within a php script every 5 minutes, to send out an email (it sends out 1 email if it finds an entry or none)

I have been adding an index for exactly this query, and when I use EXPLAIN the index is used. So I was able to make this query really fast (0.0006 seconds). But it does not help.

```
select  *
    from  tablex
    where  bz <> 'vok'
      and  date_checkout < DATE_ADD(sysdate(),INTERVAL -15 MINUTE)
      and  date_checkout > '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      and  bx=0
      and  bz <> ''
      and  nsem=0
      and  email <> 'info@xxx.com'
```

This query fills my slow-query log (I set it to 0.4 seconds)
Within the php script the query takes around 0.7 seconds.

When I copy the query and use it on phpmyadmin it takes 0.0006 seconds.

Why is there a difference for this query within the php script and from the phpmyadmin console?

Comment: How many total rows is this query returning ? PhpMyAdmin implicitly puts a `LIMIT` clause on the query being fired, to get only 25/30 rows, thus changing query performance

Comment: _"I have been adding an index for exactly this query"_ - Only one?

Comment: a) the query usually returns 1 row, maybe 2 (2nd row be worked on next time the script is called)

b) The index is a multi-index of 4 fields.

Comment: Provide an examine of your query.

Answer (score 1):

*This* composite index may help:

```
INDEX(bx, nsem,        -- first, in either order
      date_checkout)   -- last
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

If you don't need *all* the columns, spell out just the ones you do need.

Is there a reason for using `SYSDATE()` instead of `NOW()`?

`0.0006` smells like the Query cache was used.

> it sends out 1 email if it finds an entry or none

Then tack on `LIMIT 1`?

Try to avoid needing so many flags (zero `date_checkout`, nsem=0, bx=0, etc)

0.7s every 300 seconds is really insignificant.

Comment: Thanks.

I now solved the problem updating one of the index flags regulary (once a day is enough). That does not really explain the problem why "phpmyadmin" shows a fast query and within the script it is slow, but I could make the query faster. (with the updated index flag only the rows from this day are left over for further where cases, it reduced the number of rows to be searched trough from 3500 to about 20)

Answer (score 0):

So what I learned for now is, that the query-time shown in phpmyadmin does not reflect the real query time within a php script. (also when I used SQL_NO_CACHE)

I have no explanation for the time difference (0.7 vs 0.0006 seconds).

I did not change my SQL statement, but I updated the table flag nsem to -1 for all entries older than 2 days, so for now the SQL is just using nsem as an index for the query (and not the big index). nsem was a flag set to 1 when an email has been send, or 0 if not (not all entries need an email send...and they got a -1 now). Query is fast now.